# Discord.py Server Lockdown Command

Tags: discord.py

I would like to add a command to lockdown an entire server and revert the lockdown. It works, but it changed ALL the channels send messages permission to False/True. I'm asking if there is a way to set the permissions to neutral and not to change channel permissions if it is already false or true. Here is my current code:

```py
#Lockdown
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send('The server is now on lockdown!')


#unlockdown
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlockdown(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=True)
    await ctx.send('Server is now unlocked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, [passing None](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=set_permissions#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions) will delete the overwrites for the channels, putting it back to normal.